# How to search for multiply(batch) params in Spring boot?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, get, http-request-parameters

I would like to batch search for entities like that:

```
GET api/stuff?ids=123+456+789+101112+...
```

I have found out that it is possible to get the request param like that:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/stuff")
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> customQuery) {

    //After that I could get 123+456+789+101112+... and I could parse them.
    String ids = customQuery.get("ids");
}
```

Is there an alternative for the above solution which I could get the request param as a List, or any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/stuff")
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam("ids") List<Integer> ids) {

}
```

Then you should be able to call this as `api/stuff?ids=123,456,789` or as `api/stuff?ids=123&ids=456&ids=678`